Centralizers of regular unipotents in reductive monoids
Let $M$ be a reductive monoid over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, i.e. $M$ is an irreducible affine algebraic monoid whose unit group $G$ is reductive.
I'm interested in understanding the centralizer $C_M(x)$ in $M$ of a regular unipotent element $x\in G$. The centralizer $C_M(x)$ always contain the closure of $C_G(x)$, but a priori it might have extra irreducible components contained inside $M\setminus G$.

Is it possible for $C_M(x)$ to be strictly larger than $\overline{C_G(x)}$?

I know that this can happen for semisimple $x$ (there are some examples in chapter 13 of Lenner's Linear algebraic monoids, which studies centralizers of semisimple elements), but I don't have any example of these "extra irreducible components of the centrlizer" for $x$ regular unipotent.
